# Missing button for disconnect in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

Server machine MS Server 2019 Standard, 1 virtual Hyper-V MS Server 2019 Standard edition. In the Hyper-V environment session, I am missing the Disconnect button under the power button to lock and disconnect the session. Any help?

Comment: You shut the machine off with the Server VM function.  For my Hyper-V machines, I can just close the machine (Windows Close button) and the VM keeps running but closed

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing where the missing button should be.

Comment: OK, thanks. Screen is here https://ibb.co/Zxr1S8f.

Comment: Disconnect, Shut down and Restart. Disconnect is missing...

Comment: That is in your Server VM so it is a server error apparently (but not a Hyper-V issue so far as I can see)

Comment: You can use the Hyper-V Manager to shut down a machine if you wish. Spend some time learning Hyper-V functions.

Answer (score 2):

The **Disconnect** option on Windows is only when connected to a Windows host remotely (using RDP, etc.):

[image]

Given that you are not connecting remotely to it, it is not meant to be there. A VM isn't a remote session, it's as if you were sitting in front of a physical Windows machine (and the Disconnect is not there when you are at a physical Windows machine.)

To leave the Hyper-V VM running in the background while not having the screen open (which seems to be your intent) you simply close the Hyper-V window you see (by pressing the X on top of it.)

You can also start the VM in headless mode by only pressing ***Start*** in the Hyper-V Manager and not ***Connect.***

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have an additional question. The second physical server runs Windows Server 2022 and one virtual machine in Hyper-V with the same system. I have in virtual the Disconnect option there... That's why I searched if there might be a difference in versions/settings...

Comment: I would assume that one of the following is true: **1)** You don't connect to the VM there with the Hyper-V connect but instead using RDP for it (what's the title of the window in which you see the VM screen, is it 'Virtual Machine Connection' or is it 'Remote Desktop Connection'?) **2)** you're logging in to the VM but not with a local user, but instead using RDP to access a user on some other server.

Comment: If you want to lock the screen as well, you can use CTRL-ALT-END (VM version of CTRL-ALT-DEL) to access the menu and select Lock Screen.

Comment: Thank you. I am editing the problem description. Two servers (serv01, serv02) same network. Same Win server OS (2019) for serv01,02. Serv01 old DELL, serv02 new HP. Via RDP in local LAN connection to serv01/serv02 -> via Virtual Machine Connection to connect to a virtual machine. Serv01 has no Disconnect button and serv02 HAS a Disconnect button. Virtual machine in serv01 and serv02 same OS.

Comment: TBH, I can't exactly follow what you're describing her in short. But to reiterate, if you connect to a VM using the VM Manager (not RDP) you should not see a Disconnect.